# Allow PWA created in UWP not to be inactive when minimized

Tags: javascript, uwp, progressive-web-apps

Some years ago, through the Windows Bridges project I created a UWP that just loads my site.

It happens that on my site there is a setInterval (5 minutes) that sends a POST to a URL, indicating that the user is logged in.
It turns out that the default behavior of a UWP is to suspend the app when it's being minimized, so my app does not send the POST after a while.

I've read on several sites that I should use [ExtendedExecutionSession Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) to allow it to work minimized, however, all examples are in C# and I have no idea what I really should create and how to use it.

These are all the files my project contains:

- images (folder)
- msapp-error.css
- msapp-error.html
- msapp-error.js
- Package.appxmanifest

This is my [Package.appxmanifest](https://pastebin.com/DAVDadvE)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
 xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
 xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
 IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
            <Identity Name="APP-NAME" Publisher="PUBLISHER" Version="1.0.0.0" />
        <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="PhoneProductId" PhonePublisherId="PhonePublisherId"/>
    <Properties>
        <DisplayName>AppName</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>AppName</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
    </Properties>
    <Dependencies>
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    </Dependencies>
    <Resources>
        <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
    </Resources>
    <Applications>
        <Application Id="App" StartPage="https://dashboard.example.com/">
            <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="AppName"
             Description="My App Description."
             BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
             Square150x150Logo="images\Square150x150Logo.png"
             Square44x44Logo="images\Square44x44Logo.png">
                <uap:SplashScreen Image="images\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" />
                <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="images\Wide310x150Logo.png" Square310x310Logo="images\Square310x310Logo.png">
                    <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
                        <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo"/>
                        <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
                    </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
                </uap:DefaultTile>
                <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
                    <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape"/>
                </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
            </uap:VisualElements>
            <uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
                <uap:Rule Type="include" Match="https://dashboard.example.com/" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all"/>
            </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />


    </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

What should I really do?

Comment: So, your project is javascript UWP, right, and you want to implement  `ExtendedExecutionSession` with javascript right?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I want to implement ExtendedExecutionSession with JavaScript.
In fact, I do not even know what to do, I just want to add some code that makes the application never be suspended when minimized. Because my own site performs the tasks in the background and the UWP that I have just loads that remote site.
All the examples I read are complex and perform some task, and it is not my case, I just can not allow it to be suspended because my web app needs to perform the post every 5 minutes and stay connected on a socket server (Socket.IO) .

Comment: hi @Tom, I found  you posted the similar issue in MSDN, and our team has replied your case. please follow the updates.

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT The MSDN samples are only in C# and it is impossible to find some example in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified JavaScript version of the example from the [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.extendedexecution) looks like this:

```js
var session = new Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionSession();
session.reason = Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionReason.unspecified;
session.description = 'Allow background execution';
session.addEventListener('revoked', () => {
    // Extended execution revoked ...
});

session.requestExtensionAsync().then(result => {
    if (result !== Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionResult.allowed) {
        session.close();
        // Extended execution denied.
    }
});
```

I'm running this successfully in an UWP PWA.

Be sure to check if you are in a UWP context by testing if `Windows` is available:

```js
if (window.Windows) {
    // ...
}
```